# Error: Failed to install atk with mac ports

Tags: macports, putty

I got this probleml when I try to install putty with mac ports :

```
--->  Building atk
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install atk
Log for atk is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_atk/atk/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gtk2 atk gdk-pixbuf2 jasper jpeg tiff hicolor-icon-theme pango Xft2 shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXext autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext m4 automake libtool xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

I cleaned atk but I got the same error.

Comment: Actually I reinstalled OSX 10.6 then OSX 10.7 and it's work.
I reinstalled Lion 10.7 2 times. I got the same error. So weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is tracked in https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32203 it seems.

Comment: Replacing the Portfile in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/devel/atk/Portfile` with the version attached to the ticket worked for me.